# Can Bash receive parameters or return values from a C++ program?

Tags: c++, bash, user-interface, interface, dialog

There is this parser program I wrote, which returns a nice structure of the information from mutiple files (500+ entries) in form of a std::map.

One element looks like:

```
anObject -> Name [String]
            ID [Int]
            Children [list(anObject)]
```

Now I'd like to display them into a GUI. As you can see 1 object can contain more objects. All the objects existing shall then be printed by iterating through the Children of a specific object.

(e.g. "print objectA - does objectA has childen? - print children" ...)

I'm already common with "dialog" for its own, but is there an interface between dialog/bash and a C++ program, so that the dialog-GUI can interact with my map?. If not are there any good alternatives for the GUI ?

I've seen a way to run bash (and therefor dialog too) from a c program, but they weren't talking about the interface between each other.

Kind Regards

Comment: Not I am aware of. However, you could let C++ code write to a file and parse by bash.

Comment: Yes I know, but that would be using a parser for a parser, which sounds painful

Comment: I agree with Billz, I think writing to file and then reading that file in bash would be the easiest way out..

Comment: @user3159253 this may be an option, but it sounds like I have to start from scratch for interpreting and menu design - I thought I could use some predefined functions, which are available in e.g. `dialog`

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind:

The C++ program runs once and produces an output file that the bash scripts picks up and works with. While, as  you say this seems double the work, C++ is parsing produces some stuff which bash then needs to parse, this is actually quite consistent with general scripting philosophy: chaining specific tools (grep, sort, tail , sed ...) together to achieve some larger goal. We delegate the hard stuff to some specialised program and produce a nicely formatted result that bash can easily use. This implies that you might tweak the C++ output to be really easily parsed in bash.

An alternative is to have the C++ program effectively run in the background as a service. In the most general case it could be Web Service or REST service. So your UI simply issues (say) HTTP requests to the service and consumes the answers. I think using named pipes you can more simply interact with a background process, but it's years since Indid this with bash, so I've no idea whether it's practical for a UI.

Overall my feeling is that if your real goal is to make a nice UI then bash is not the best tool, PHP or any web app building tools are probably easier. However if learning bash is the goal then exploring named pipes may be fun.

Comment: I'm not focused on Bash/Dialog, but as far as I've seen it's the fastest and easiest way to generate a GUI and since the Code is *very* short, this makes it easy to maintain (especially if a different developer than me touches the code). The idea with managing as service sounds like it could work, but on the other hand it sounds terrible to know what's happening ATM - I'd like to have it easy for other developers